# Use a custom component to alter the value of a formControl

Tags: angular

I'm building a reactive form within my angular app. I have a small reusable component that I built, and I'd like to use that component to alter the value of one of the formControls within my formGroup. However I can't seem to get it wired up properly.

Simply using `formControlName` like you do with a `matInput` or `mat-slide-toggle` doesn't seem to work the same.

My reusable component is making use of a input within itself, is there anyway I can link this to the formControl in my group?

Reusable component usage

```
<app-tenant-picker 
    (selectedTenant)="changeSelectedTenant($event)"
    formControlName="tenant">
</app-tenant-picker>
```

Reusable component html

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
        <mat-icon class="search-icon" matSuffix>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
        <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="tenantListFormControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
               autocomplete="off">
        <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete"
                          [displayWith]="displayTenantNameInAutocomplete"
                                              (optionSelected)="emitTenant($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let tenant of filteredTenantList$ | async" [value]="tenant">
                {{tenant.name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

`(selectedTenant)` is just a simple eventEmitter: `@Output() selectedTenant = new EventEmitter<Tenant>();`

FormGroup

```
this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
        name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        comment: new FormControl(''),
        tenant: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        sources: new FormArray([]),
        include: this.includeLocation,
        location: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        locationComment: new FormControl('')
      });
```

Other

```
selectedTenant: Tenant;
...
changeSelectedTenant(tenant: Tenant) {
    this.selectedTenant = tenant;
    console.log("ST: ",this.selectedTenant);
  }
```

If there's anything else I've missed, let me know and I'll add it to the question.

Comment: I think you need to write a [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) for your custom control/component. Angular provides these for the standard controls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `ControlValueAccessor` on your custom component

Read more about it [here](https://dev.to/bitovi/understanding-angular-s-control-value-accessor-interface-5e7k)  and [here](https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/angular-2-custom-form-control-with-validation-json-input-2b4cf9bc2d73)